# How do I run compile this typescript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found some code I wanted to try and run, but am not quite sure where to go with it. The code is for creating accounts on textnow.com, and I'm struggling to figure out how to run it. If anyone could help I would be grateful!

```
// import dependencies
import * as request from 'request-promise';
import * as md5 from 'md5';
import { URL } from 'url';
import areaCodes from './area-codes';
import { processLoop } from '../../utils';
import { Logger, DebugLevel } from '../../logger';
import { fakeTextNowBonusInfo } from '../../faker';

export class TextNowRegistration {
  private readonly API_BASE = 'https://api.textnow.me/api2.0';
  private readonly API_SECRET = '851a9f2bad15843c1a922890c061830e8ce50e86840575d17e61ef0becdc3576';
  private readonly SITE_KEY = '6LcU4gkTAAAAAM4SyYTmXlKvqwWLuaFLy-30rzBn';
  private readonly AREA_CODE = 540;

  private username: string;
  private password: string;
  private email: string;
  private clientId: string;
  private captchaToken: string;
  private logger: Logger;
  private onCaptchaReceived: (siteKey: string) => Promise<string>;

  constructor(username: string, password: string, email: string, onCaptchaReceived: (siteKey: string) => Promise<string>) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.onCaptchaReceived = onCaptchaReceived;
    this.clientId = null;
    this.captchaToken = null;
    this.logger = new Logger(username);
  }

  private buildSignature(method: string, uri: string, json: any) : string {
    // strip base uri
    let path = uri.replace(this.API_BASE+'/', '');

    // prepare json payload
    let stringified = '';
    if (json) {
      stringified = JSON.stringify(json);
    }

    // hash the payload
    return md5(this.API_SECRET + method + path + stringified);
  }

  private buildUrl(path: string) : string {
    return this.API_BASE + path;
  }

  public register() : Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.logger.normal(`signing up new user: ${this.username}`);
      this.checkUsername().then((usernameExists: boolean) => {
        // check fif username already exists
        if (usernameExists) throw new Error('the user could not be created as the username is not available');
        return this.checkEmail();
      })
      .then((emailExists: boolean) => {
        // check if email already exists
        if (emailExists) throw new Error('the user could not be created as the email is already registered');
        return this.signUp();
      })
      .then(() => {
        return this.validateCaptcha();
      }).then(() => {
        return this.claimPhoneNumber(this.AREA_CODE);
      }).then((phoneNumber: string) => {
        return resolve(phoneNumber);
      }).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  private checkUsername() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      // prepare json request
      this.makeRequest({
        uri: this.buildUrl(`/users/${this.username}?idfa=&idfv=&client_type=TN_IOS_FREE`),
        method: 'HEAD'
      }).then((data: any) => {
        this.logger.red(`the user '${this.username}' is already existing`);
        return resolve(true);
      }).catch((err: any) => {
        this.logger.normal(`the user '${this.username}' is not registered yet`);
        return resolve(false);
      })
    });
  }

  private checkEmail() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      // prepare json request
      this.makeRequest({
        uri: this.buildUrl(`/emails/${this.email}?idfa=&idfv=&client_type=TN_IOS_FREE`),
        method: 'HEAD'
      }).then((data: any) => {
        this.logger.red(`the email '${this.email}' is already registered`);
        return resolve(true);
      }).catch((err: any) => {
        this.logger.normal(`the email '${this.email}' is not registered yet`);
        return resolve(false);
      })
    });
  }

  private signUp() : Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      // prepare json request
      let body = {
        'dob': '2018-02-17',
        'password': this.password,
        'email': this.email,
        'bonus_info': fakeTextNowBonusInfo()
      };
      // make the code verification request
      this.makeRequest({
        uri: this.buildUrl(`/users/${this.username}?idfa=&idfv=&client_type=TN_IOS_FREE`),
        method: 'PUT',
        body: body
      }).then((data: any) => {
        // check if registration was successfull
        if (!data.result || !data.result.id) {
          throw new Error('there was an error trying to register the user');
        }
        // the user was successfully created
        this.logger.green('successfully registered user');
        this.clientId = data.result.id;
        let url = new URL(data.result.captcha_link);
        this.captchaToken = url.searchParams.get('token');
        return resolve(this.clientId);
      }).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  private claimPhoneNumber(areaCode: number) : Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      // make the phone number claim request
      this.logger.normal('claiming phone number with area code: ' + areaCode);
      this.makeRequest({
        uri: this.buildUrl(`/users/${this.username}/phone?idfa=&idfv=&client_id=${this.clientId}&client_type=TN_IOS_FREE`),
        method: 'PUT',
        body: {
          'area_code': areaCode
        }
      }).then((phone: any) => {
        const phoneNumber: string = '+1' + phone;
        this.logger.yellow('claimed phone number: ' + phoneNumber);
        return resolve(phoneNumber);
      }).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  private validateCaptcha() : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      // wait for the captcha to be returned
      this.logger.normal('requested a new recaptcha token');
      this.onCaptchaReceived(this.SITE_KEY).then((token: string) => {
        this.logger.normal('received fresh recaptcha token');
        // prepare json payload
        let body = {
          u: this.captchaToken,
          c: token
        };
        // prepare request
        return request({
          uri: 'https://www.textnow.com/api/identity/validate',
          method: 'POST',
          form: {
            json: JSON.stringify(body)
          },
          json: true,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14C92'
          }
        });
      }).then((data: any) => {
        // check if the validation was successful
        if (data.error_code !== null) throw new Error('there was an error validating the captcha');
        // the validation was successful
        this.logger.normal('successfully validated user captcha');
        return resolve(); 
      }).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  private getRandomAreaCode() : number {
    const length: number = areaCodes.length;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  }

  private makeRequest(options: request.OptionsWithUri) : request.RequestPromise {
    // modify and add required headers
    //options.proxy = 'http://localhost:8888';
    options.json = true;
    options.headers = {
      'User-Agent': 'TextNowSwift-Free/8.20.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.2; Scale/2.00)',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1'
    };
    // add signature
    options.uri = options.uri + '&signature=' + this.buildSignature(options.method, (options.uri as string), options.body);
    // make request
    return request(options);
  }
}
```

I converted the code into .js and tried running it, but I was given this error:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jashua\Desktop\script.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Comment: you dont have to convert it .. you can run the code by compiling it using  `tsc`

Comment: you need to check if you have installed `request-promise` in node_modules.

Comment: Run npm install in your project root directory. If request-promise is not in your package.json you will have to add that dependency through npm

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be missing some or all of the modules listed in the import statements.

Install node/npm, go to the same directory where you have this script file and run

```
npm i <module>
```

for each missing module, where `<module>` is what comes after the `from` keyword in each import statement. Note, though, that some import statements are relative (those staring with `.` or `..`) and node will expect to find them at those locations for the script to successfully run.

Other than this basic tip, I recommend you take a look at npm documentation and typescript compiler options for a more in depth understanding.